# Why does stopping a MuleSoft flow cause the Quartz 'repeat interval' to stop working?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

We have MuleSoft application that is triggered by a Quartz connector.

Also in the application is a flow that starts with an FTP inbound-endpoint that pings for files on an FTP server.  When files are detected, they're read.  All good to this point.

We needed to stop the FTP inbound-endpoint so it doesn't ping all day.  Thus, we want to turn OFF (i.e. stop) the flow that contains the FTP transport connector.

The problem?  During testing, our quartz job is set to run every few minutes.   If we do *not* stop the flow with the FTP reader, then the Quartz repeat interval works.  Every little bit the app kicks off.  Perfect... sort of.

BUT... when we *stop* the flow programmatically via a Java component, as we want to do, then the Quartz repeat interval never repeats.  It runs the one time on start-up, then sits forever after that.

Is there something internally that fouls up the Quartz timing control when a Flow is stopped on one of the application's components?

Here is the Flow with the Quartz job.  The flow we want to stop is down inside Main.

```
<flow name="offline-pricing-flow" doc:name="offline-pricing-flow"> 
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="OLP" repeatInterval="300000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" cronExpression="0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *"> 
        <quartz:event-generator-job></quartz:event-generator-job>  
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>  
    <flow-ref name="init-flow" doc:name="Init"></flow-ref>  
    <flow-ref name="main-flow" doc:name="Main" doc:description="Main processing."></flow-ref>  
</flow>
```

Here is the code where we stop the flow:

```
FlowConstruct flow = context.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("file-service-flow");

if (flow != null && flow.getMuleContext().isStarted()) {
    try {

        flow.getMuleContext().stop();

    } catch (MuleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Earlier in the app we attempt to start it this way in the component:

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

    FlowConstruct flow = eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("file-service-flow");

    if (flow != null && flow.getMuleContext().isStopped()) {
        try {

            flow.getMuleContext().start();

        } catch (MuleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was my own.

Up above I described this action, and asked why my Quartz job stopped, but what was happening was that I was actually stopping the MuleContext--not the flow itself.  This was my incorrect attempt.

```
FlowConstruct flow = context.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("file-service-flow");

if (flow != null && flow.getMuleContext().isStarted()) {
    try {

        flow.getMuleContext().stop();

    } catch (MuleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can see now how I was half-guessing.

Here is the correct way.  I found an example finally where I could see that my registry look-up was wrong.

I needed to cast the look-up to the AbstractFlowConstruct instead of the FlowConstruct.  It worked perfectly after that.  I am smarter now.

```
AbstractFlowConstruct f = (AbstractFlowConstruct) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct("my-flow");

if (f.isStarted()) {
    try {
        f.stop();
    } catch (MuleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```